# DataTables Search Boolean

Tags: datatables

I am having difficulty applying a search on a three state dropdown (any, yes, and no) on a Boolean column in my DataTables object.

Here is a sample row of my data:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Email": "JohnDoe@email.com",
    "Elevated": true,
    "Activated": true
}
```

This is my markup for the dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" id="elevated">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

And this is what I'm using to search the column:

```
const elevated = $("#elevated option:selected").val();
grid.column("Elevated:name").search(elevated).draw();
```

What is happening is that it will clear the search whenever the dropdown option is any, but whenever the dropdown option is yes or no it returns no rows.

It doesn't matter if I set the option values to 1/0 or if I specify the RegEx parameter in the search method. The results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scowering a bunch of forums I found out what was going on. I was using columns.render to display an icon based on the value of the cell. Doing this caused it to mess with columns.search. Instead, I replaced columns.render with columns.createdCell, manipulated the existing DOM to display my icon, and then columns.search worked as expected.